# Monad Transformers lift

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, lifting

I was just looking into monad transformers in real world Haskell.
The book said that to make something a monad transformer, you need to make it an instance of the MonadTrans type class.

So the book defined a new Transformer, the `MaybeT m a` transformer.

They defined the monadTrans type class for this new transformer:

```
instance MonadTrans MaybeT where
  lift m = MaybeT (Just `liftM` m)
```

Then they made an instance of MonadState for this transformer:

```
instance (MonadState s m) => MonadState s (MaybeT m) where
  get = lift get
  put k = lift (put k)
```

From what I understand the lift function is taking the underlying monad and wrapping it in the right constructor. However, I do not get the implementation of get or put in the MonadState type class, I would like some help in understanding what the lift is actually doing here. I have also heard that in the mtl package because of how the type classes are defined, you can have a stack of monad transformers with WriterT, StateT etc but you can use functions like get,put,tell etc without actually doing any lifting. I was wondering how does this work, I strongly suspect its to do with these type classes but I am not sure?

Answer (score 1):

> but you can use functions like get,put,tell etc without actually doing any lifting

This is because those functions are actually defined on e.g. the `MonadState` typeclass, not `State` type.

```
class Monad m => MonadState s m | m -> s where
    get :: m s
    put :: s -> m ()
```

Then, both `State` and `StateT` are made an instance of that class, which makes using those possible<sup>1</sup>

In your example instance, if we know that the inner monad of `MaybeT m` is (fulfills) `MonadState s`, we can treat the whole outer monad as `MonadState s` provided we lift the operations directed to the inner monad so that they fit the outer one, which done with `lift`.

In plain english, that would sound something like "*If the MaybeT transformer transforms (wraps) over some monad `m` that is a stateful (`MonadState`) monad for type `s`, the resulting type also is a stateful monad for that type*".

---

<sup>1</sup>This is actually just one instance, because `State s a` is actually implemented as `StateT s Identity a`. [Refer to the sources](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/src/Control-Monad-State-Class.html#MonadState) for the implementation details.

Comment: So if we had something like `MaybeT (State Int) String` and then we used get on this, what happens, I think I am having trouble understanding how the actual lifting is working. What is being passed to the lift function?

Comment: @Zubair `lift` takes an action directed to the inner monad and returns it wrapped in the outer monad. IOW, in this particular case, `lift :: State Int String -> MaybeT (State Int) String`.